# Android GDX game detect the right shape?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am developing a Gdx game but I have got stuck on some part and I will explain briefly about it:

I have 9 balls organized on 3*3 and I need to detect the ball that I'm touching as shown in the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCTSj.png)

and I typed this code:

```
for (int i : listBalls) {

    touchPoint = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
    rectangle = new Rectangle(sprite[i].getX(), sprite[i].getY(), spriteSize, spriteSize);

    if (rectangle.contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {

        Gdx.app.log("Test", "Touched dragged " + String.valueOf(i));
        pointer = i;
    }
}
```

In case of touching any ball of the above row, it detects the opposite ball in the bottom row. For example in the above image, if I touch ball no 2 on the top it will point to ball no 8, and same if touching any of the bottom balls.

In case of touching any ball of the middle ball, it gives the right on.

I hope I could explain clearly my issue. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained here: [LibGDX input y-axis flipped](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/103145/libgdx-input-y-axis-flipped) the coordinate system of the input is inverted on the y-axis, try substracting the screen height of your device or camera

```
int y = screenHeight - Gdx.input.getY();
```

Keep in mind that using a [Camera](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Orthographic-camera) and unprojecting the input coordinates is the most recommended way to go about detecting input in LibGDX. Example:

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    Vector3 unprojected = camera.unproject(new Vector3(screenX, screenY,0));
}
```

You don't even have to invert the y-coordinate, `unproject()` does this automatically for you. To use the correct x and y coordinates you then could use:

```
float x = unprojected.x;
float y = unprojected.y;
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer as correct since it helped you solve your problem and for other developers to know! :3